# How is my reference to a struct member still valid after the struct was moved?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm creating a reference to a structure member using a function (named `get`), then I move the struct using another function (named `pr`), then I dereference the previously created pointer.

Am I in the wrong here (a.k.a. working by accident), or is my reference is still valid by some rule?

```
struct MyStruct {
    inner: i32,
}

fn get(a: &MyStruct) -> &i32 {
    return &a.inner;
}

fn pr(a: MyStruct) {
    println!("MyStruct {}", a.inner);
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let x = MyStruct { inner: 3 };
    let &i = get(&x);
    pr(x);
    println!("i {}", i);
}
```

The [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) outputs:

```
Hello, world!
MyStruct 3
i 3
```

Comment: I'm by no means a Rust expert yet (I'm working on it..). However, the ampersand before the variable name is incorrect. That said, it _is_ what is causing this to work. If you change it to `let i = get(&x);` instead, an `&i32` is returned and the compiler correctly errors because of the move, as you expected. TLDR: I am unsure why the ampersand on the _variable name_ is causing this to work. I could also just be forgetting something basic... so (shrug).

Comment: In Rust, `&foo` is a *reference* and `*const foo` is a *raw pointer*. I've updated your text to match your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `let` expression gets pattern-matched and

```
let &i = get(&x); // i.e. a &i32
```

Results in `i` being assigned to `i32` and since `i32` is copyable, there is no ownership violation.

The Rust reference states that "a let statement introduces a new set of variables, given by a pattern" ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#let-statements)) and "patterns consist of some combination of literals, destructured arrays or enum constructors, structs and tuples, variable binding specifications" ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#match-expressions)).

The left-hand side of the binding, `&i` is not just a literal, which tells the compiler that it should try to pattern-match against the right-hand side expression. In this case it results in `i` pointing to a copyable value (`i32`) and not a reference (`&i32`). In other words:

```
let &i = get(&x);
```

is equivalent to

```
let i = *get(&x);
```

So `x` is not borrowed and `pr(x)` is still applicable.

Comment: This was my assumption but I could only find vague references to this possibility. Do you have any reference material? I am really struggling to find something that can explain this.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Unfortunately the [section on destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/patterns.html#destructuring) is not explicit on this. But since the type of `i` is `i32` (no reference) it must be moved or copied. You can test that it doesn't work in general by replacing `i32` by something that is not copyable, e.g. some new struct `Int` (I just did that).

Comment: @starblue I am aware of how the basics of copyable and non-copyable types work. What I don't understand is why the variable binding is pattern matched and then destructured "in-place". Knowing this makes the copyable reasoning perfectly valid... but how do we get to the point of this being a pattern matching situation? Have I completely overlooked that you can pattern match in a let binding without the `match` keyword? If so.. that seems to be skipped in almost ALL Rust material I have come across.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6f92507aeed24ae49171b02c48051bfd&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: `let (v1, v2, result) = uglyfunction(v1, v2)` comes to mind. It's the example at the end of the _ownership_ section, right before _borrowing_.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes you have overlooked that, but since it just sneaks in in examples (e.g. in [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/patterns.html#ignoring-bindings)) you have a valid excuse.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I completely skipped over this part and didn't quite grasp the semantics of the left hand side of a let binding. I have never seen it used in this way either.. which added to the confusion. Thank you all!