# What's the semantic of assignment in Rust?

Tags: rust

How could know the type of a binding if I use auto type deduction when creating a binding? what if the expression on the right side is a borrow(like `let x = &5;`), will it be value or a borrow? What will happen if I re-assign a borrow or a value?

Just for check, I do can re-assign a borrow if I use `let mut x: &mut T = &mut T{};` or `let mut x:&T = & T{};`, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is my reference to a struct member still valid after the struct was moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586277/how-is-my-reference-to-a-struct-member-still-valid-after-the-struct-was-moved)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I sense some confusion between *binding* and *assigning*:

- **Binding** introduces a new variable, and associates it to a value,
- **Assigning** overwrites a value with another.

This can be illustrated in two simple lines:

```
let mut x = 5;    //  Binding
x = 10;           //  Assigning
```

---

A **binding** may appear in multiple places in Rust:

- `let` statements,
- `if let`/`while let` conditions,
- cases in a `match` expression,
- and even in a `for` expression, on the left side of `in`.

Whenever there is a **binding**, Rust's grammar also allows *pattern matching*:

- in the case of `let` statements and `for` expressions, the patterns must be irrefutable,
- in the case of `if let`, `while let` and `match` cases, the patterns may fail to match.

Pattern matching means that the type of the variable introduced by the binding differs based on how the binding is made:

```
let x = &5;    //  x: &i32
let &y = &5;   //  y: i32
```

---

**Assigning** always requires using `=`, the assignment operator.

When assigning, the former value is overwritten, and `drop` is called on it if it implements `Drop`.

```
let mut x = 5;
x = 6;
//  Now x == 6, drop was not called because it's a i32.

let mut s = String::from("Hello, World!");
s = String::from("Hello, 神秘德里克!");
//  Now s == "Hello, 神秘德里克!", drop was called because it's a String.
```

The value that is overwritten may be as simple as an integer or float, a more involved `struct` or `enum`, or a *reference*.

```
let mut r = &5;
r = &6;
//  Now r points to 6, drop was not called as it's a reference.
```

Overwriting a *reference* does not overwrite the value pointed to by the reference, but the reference itself. The original value still lives on, and will be dropped when it's ready.

To overwrite the pointed to value, one needs to use `*`, the dereference operator:

```
let mut x = 5;
let r = &mut x;
*r = 6;
//  r still points to x, and now x = 6.
```

If the type of the dereferenced value requires it, `drop` will be called:

```
let mut s = String::from("Hello, World!");
let r = &mut s;
*r = String::from("Hello, 神秘德里克!");
//  r still points to s, and now s = "Hello, 神秘德里克!".
```

I invite you to use to playground to and toy around, you can [start from here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=75117d9d3cb1e0616fe36770e40a378f&version=stable):

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("Hello, World!");
    {
        let r = &mut s;
        *r = String::from("Hello, 神秘德里克!");
    }
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

---

Hopefully, things should be a little clearer now, so let's check your samples.

```
let x = &5;
```

`x` is a reference to i32 (`&i32`). What happens is that the compiler will introduce a temporary in which `5` is stored, and then borrow this temporary.

```
let mut x: &mut T = T{};
```

Is impossible. The type of `T{}` is `T` not `&mut T`, so this fails to compile. You could change it to `let mut x: &mut T = &mut T{};`.

And your last example is similar.

Comment: What's the semantic of assignment? Can I overwrite a borrow with a value or vice versa or it's just compile error because type don't match? If I overwrite a value with another value, will drop be called on that original value?

Comment: @神秘德里克: I have extended the answer with more details on assignments. Hopefully it will clears things up.