# When does Rust drop the value in case of reassignment?

Tags: rust

```
struct Item {
    name: String,
}

impl Item {
    fn new(x: &str) -> Item {
        Item { name: String::from(x) }
    }

    fn change_name(&mut self, x: &str) {
        self.name = String::from(x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut item1 = Item::new("Foo");
    item1.change_name("Bar");
}
```

When I call `item1.change_name()`, what will happen to the `String("Foo")` assigned to the `name` previously. When will `drop()` be called on the `String("Foo")`? Will this leak memory?

Comment: Of course there is no leak in this case. Do you imagine a modern language with such a flaw?

Comment: just test it https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=463feb204a32376690c1cd5da6af8e45

Answer (score 6):

After some research I got the answer.

When a new value is assigned to a variable (by overwriting, not by shadowing) then the old value will be dropped as part of the assignment operation.

**Reference**

- [Does Rust free up the memory of overwritten variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227347/does-rust-free-up-the-memory-of-overwritten-variables)
- [What's the semantic of assignment in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648958/whats-the-semantic-of-assignment-in-rust)